# Different results when query is made from phpmyadmin and when query is made by my php web aplication

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

This is the query string i'm using:

```
"SELECT *"
. "FROM cad_processo"
. "WHERE cad_processo.entrada >=  DATE_FORMAT(NOW() , '%Y=%m-01')"
. "AND cad_processo.entrada<=NOW()";`
```

When i use it on my application it doesn't returns any results, but when i'm using it in phpMyAdmin it returns the correct results(3 rows). What might be the cause to this?

Comment: Yes, because the query has syntax errors due to the lack of spacing between things like `*FROM`. Echo your query out an you'll see the errors or check your error logs.

Comment: Fixed that and it keeps returning no results at all

Comment: And btw this was just my mistake when typing the query here

Comment: Don't type your query/code here. Copy and paste so we know we are looking at the same code. Can you show your PHP usage?

Comment: I think the code is too big for a coment, but basically i only need the row count of this query to fill another table and then plot a graph with the results from table 2.
 ` $queryCONSULTA = "SELECT * "
                . "FROM cad_processo "
                . "WHERE cad_processo.entrada >=  DATE_FORMAT(NOW() , '%Y=%m-01') "
                . "AND cad_processo.entrada<=NOW()";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $queryCONSULTA);
        $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        mysqli_free_result($result);`

Comment: Use the `edit` link under the tags of your question. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38313533/edit.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look well-formed to me.  Might need a few spaces.

```
SELECT *FROM cad_processoWHERE cad_processo.entrada >=  DATE_FORMAT(NOW() , '%Y=%m-01')AND cad_processo.entrada<=NOW();
```